# When did Phineas and Ferb do nothing?

Tags: phineas-and-ferb

I was attempting a *Phineas and Ferb* [quiz](https://www.proprofs.com/quiz-school/quizshow.php?title=do-you-really-know-phineas-ferb&q=3&next=n) but I got one question's answer wrong:

[image]

That made me wonder when did that happen? I remember them doing something  everyday. What was the day or days when they did nothing?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

## [The Best Lazy Day Ever](http://phineasandferb.wikia.com/wiki/The_Best_Lazy_Day_Ever)

Season 1, Episode 28.

From the wikia:

> Phineas and Ferb decide to do absolutely nothing for the day. Candace questions her purpose in life after realizing that she can't bust her brothers for doing nothing. Meanwhile, Dr. Doofenshmirtz is tired of being the ugliest person around, so he invents a device that can turn anything and anyone ugly.

From the [transcript](http://phineasandferb.wikia.com/wiki/The_Best_Lazy_Day_Ever/Transcript):

> **Phineas**: You know, Ferb, everyday we do something really big. But you know the one thing we haven't done? Relax. I say we take advantage of this perfect day and have the best do-nothing day ever.

Comment: I don't remember that episode... did they actually succeed (in doing nothing)? If so, what was the episode about... were they not the focus of the episode?

Comment: @JeffC - it's all about Candace trying to convince them to do something and failing ;) https://youtu.be/p_I0sfSFrno

Comment: This is a terrible use of the English language, by the way. I go to work every workday. When I was a toddler, I didn't. That doesn't mean I don't go to work everyday.